# Как в excel сделать автоматическое форматирование? jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, excel, table

Есть HTML таблица, по кнопке экспортируется в Excel документ.

Как сделать перенос строк в ячейках ?

Использую библиотеку [tableexport](https://tableexport.v5.travismclarke.com/#tableexport)

*Вот так данные попадают в excel файл:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Как сделать вот такой перенос?*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-inverse" tableexport-key="jsGrid">
   <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
         <th>Кол 1</th>
         <th>Кол 2</th>
         <th>Кол 3</th>
         <th>Кол 4</th>
         <th>Кол 5</th>
         <th>Кол 6</th>
         <th>Кол 7</th>
         <th>Кол 8</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="export_xls_table">
      <tr>
         <td>-</td>
         <td>ТОО USER COMPANY </td>
         <td>Hello <br> World</td>
         <td>
            <div>
               <span>Номер 1 </span>
               <span>Hello <br> World</span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
               <span>Номер 1 </span>
               <span>Hello <br> World</span>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>-</td>
         <td>
            <div>Hello World</div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div>Hello World</div>
            <div>Hello World</div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div>Hello World</div>
            <div>Hello World</div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: в *Excel* код символа перенос строки 10:  *Chr(10)*

Comment: @vikttur Читал про это, как мне использовать это при экспорте?

Comment: Не знаю *jquery*, только подсказка, как реализовывается в *VBA*: *"Hello" & Chr(10) & "World"*. Если не поможет - попытка не пытка....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нашел как это сделать с подобными библиотеками.

Реализовал через PHP, получилось проще.

Создал файл `export_xls.php` в него с помощью jQuery и HTML передал таблицу и скачал.

```
<?php 
 $table = $_POST['HTMLTABLE'];

 $xls_file="Export table.xls"; 

 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_file");

 echo $table; 
?>
```

---

*Результат:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]